# I accidently run this script. My Internet is now blocked

Tags: internet

I run this script now I wanna undo changes it made.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Firewall apps - only allow apps run from "internet" group to run

# clear previous rules
sudo iptables -F

# accept packets for internet group
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner --gid-owner internet -j ACCEPT

# also allow local connections
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 192.168.0.1/24 -j ACCEPT

# reject packets for other users
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -j REJECT

# open a shell with internet access
sudo -g internet -s
```

Comment: I think changing the `-A` to `-D` or -`R` might remove the entries/

Answer (score 2):

This should do:

```
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

Comment: I really appreciate ur help buddy god bless you :)

Comment: You're welcome. Could you accept/flag it as an answer? I am still collecting rewards to get full access. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could reboot, or run:

```
sudo iptables -F
```

This will flush all the rules that are set.

Comment: Niels van Adrichem's answer is much more detailed/complete, although the other commands are not necessary if there were no rules set before the script was run.